# Term for maximal proper divisors

Tags: elementary-number-theory, terminology

What do you call a divisor, $d$, of a number $n$ which is of the form $d = n/p$ where $p$ is a prime divisor of $n$? For a cryptography class I need to discuss such numbers (to describe how to find primitive roots) and would like a handy name for them. But I fear that the students would be thrown off by the use of the word "maximal" even though it is correct from a lattice-theoretic perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If maximal proper divisors is the proper term then you should probably stick with that. I'm currently taking a cryptography class and the lecturer has used the same term, but I found the way you phrased the definition here much clearer and easier to understand so I think it'll be fine

Comment: I went with that term. I was just making sure that I wasn't overlooking anything. The students didn't have as much trouble with the concept as I had feared they might.